# Moment.js returns 1 as last day of month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get the last day of the month as an integer. So for the month december 31 should be returned.

```
moment().endOf('month').day()
```

This will, however, return 1 - even though

```
moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

returns the correct date. Can someone explain why and how to get the actual day?

Comment: Is it your actual code? seems like 31 october which is monday

Comment: `moment().endOf('month').date()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the day of the month, you have to use `.date()` instead. See the relevant part of the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/

Answer (score 1):

`day()` returns the day of the week, not the date

You want to use `date()` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
moment().endOf('month').format('DD')
```

also

```
moment().endOf('month').date();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastDate = moment().endOf('month').format('DD')
```

which returns the day and you can parseInt this for making it as integer

Answer (score -1):

As galchen said, day() returns the day of the week. To get the date, manipulate the string:

```
var lastDay = moment().endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD').split('-')[2];
```

Comment: if you wish to use `.format` then why not `.format('DD')`

Comment: This is unnecessary, just use `.date()`.